# Can I dynamically change a styles attribute in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a simple progress bar that will dynamically change based on the current state. I am using two views, one for the progress bar container and one for the progress bar  (which is visually shown by dynamically changing in width). How can I dynamically update the progress bar width style?

Here's what I have (I'm importing the stylesheet):

```
<View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
   <View style ={styles.progressBar} />
</View>

progressBarContainer: {
    width: 300,
    height: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black'
  },
  progressBar: {
    height: 16,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'purple'
  }
```

Comment: You can do it inline, as the `styles` object won't be aware of `this`. Also as you say it's imported so mutating it is not the best idea. You can try this: `{ [styles.progressBar, {width: this.state.progressBarWidth} ]}`

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can. something like this.

```
<View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
   <View 
   style={ this.state.pressStatus ? styles.buttonPress : styles.button }
/>
</View>
```